# UITableView scroll to specific section using UIPIckerView?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uipickerview

I have a UITableView that has a fixed number of sections, however the number of rows in each section can vary depending on server results.

I would like to implement a picker wheel to "jump" to each section. Here are my UIPickerView delegate methods in the UITableViewController:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{

return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
return 5;
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
return [self.pickerArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

The "pickerArray" which is initialized in ViewDidLoad:

```
self.pickerArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Watching", @"Completed", @"On Hold", @"Dropped", @"Planned", nil];
```

and here's my didSelectRow method:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[self.pickerArray objectAtIndex:row] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone  animated:YES];
}
```

I noticed there's no "scrollTo**section**AtIndexPath" method, which would be helpful. Apple's docs say this about the "indexpath" parameter:

```
indexPath
An index path that identifies a row in the table view by its row index and its section index.
```

Calling the method (picking something in the picker) throws this fault:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString
>   section]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4bdb8'

Any idea what I should be doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` method takes an `NSIndexPath` as the first parameter but the code is passing an `NSString` resulting in the exception.

As the docs say, an `NSIndexPath` includes both a section and row (you must know this since you populated a table view with sections).

You need to create an `NSIndexPath` that corresponds to the first row of the section in the table view that relates to the `row` selected in the picker view.

So assuming that the `row` of the picker view corresponds directly to the sections in your table view:

```
//"row" below is row selected in the picker view
NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:row];

[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip 
                      atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone 
                              animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. It worked perfectly. I need to read more carefully.