# How to programmatically have UITableView scroll to a specific section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my calendar app, I want my UITableView to scroll to a specific section based on which date is tapped. Current implementation is below:

```
- (void)calendarDidDateSelected:(JTCalendar *)calendar date:(NSDate *)date
{
    // Format NSDate so it can be compared to date selected
    static NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = nil;
    if(!dateFormatter){
        dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd"; // Read the documentation for dateFormat
    }

    // Set formatted dates
    NSDate *juneSixteenth = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2015-06-16"];
    NSDate *juneSeventeenth = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2015-06-17"];

    // Set date selected, so agendaTable knows which event to show
    if([juneSixteenth compare:date] == NSOrderedSame){
        NSLog(@"You picked June 16th");
        self.datePicked = [NSNumber numberWithInt:16];
    }
    else if([juneSeventeenth compare:date] == NSOrderedSame){
        NSLog(@"You picked June 17th");
        self.datePicked = [NSNumber numberWithInt:17];
    }
    else {
        _datePicked = nil;
        NSLog(@"Date: %@", date);
    }
    [self.agendaTable reloadData];
}
```

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508752/uitableview-scroll-to-specific-section-using-uipickerview) that says to do it like so:

```
       if([juneSixteenth compare:date] == NSOrderedSame){
            NSLog(@"You picked June 16th");
            self.datePicked = [NSNumber numberWithInt:16];

            //"row" below is row selected in the picker view
            NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:row];

            [self.agendaTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip
                          atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone
                                  animated:YES];
        }
```

This gives an error stating that `row` is an undeclared identifier, and I want it to use the section index rather than the row anyway. How would I implement this?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Try this

```
[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:NSNotFound inSection:section]
```

Comment: Works great on iOS10/11. Elegant solution!

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me

Comment: how to use it with tableview ?!!

Comment: For Swift version of this answer, see @VictorCasé's [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53364343/16602527).

Answer (score 21):

Swift 3.0

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 'item', section: 'section')
   self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Swift version of @black-sheep answer:

```
let sectionIndexPath = IndexPath(row: NSNotFound, section: section)
```

Answer (score 9):

When your section has no cells, for example it has just a header or footer, you can use one of the following options:

```
let sectionRect = yourTable.rect(forSection: sectionNumber)
yourTable.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: sectionRect.origin.x, y: sectionRect.origin.y), animated: true)
```

or

```
let sectionRect = yourTable.rect(forSection: sectionNumber)
yourTable.scrollRectToVisible(sectionRect, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 7):

**Row** is must be int value and that variable define in .h and use this variable in anywhere in .m class  that you are want to scroll on particular position.

You can scroll UITableView on particular section and also you can scroll to section's particular index cell using following code:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[MytblView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
                     atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop 
                             animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to find/calculate the `section` and `row` that you want to scroll

```
NSInteger row = ??;//you have to find/calculate which row you want to show
NSInteger section = ??;//you have to find/calculate which row of the sections you want to show
NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];

[self.agendaTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip
                        atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone
                                animated:YES];
```