# Scroll to specific header view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i have a table view with different sections. Each section has its on headerview. After clicking a button I want to scroll to a specific header view.

The following method does not work, cause my last section can be expanded (rows visible) or collapsed (number or rows == 0).

```
self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .middle, animated: true)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/31018517/8552611

Comment: Would it be possible to check the indexPath to see if the position you want to scoll to is currently collapsed, and if so, programmatically expand that section before scrolling there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0 ), at: .top, animated: true)
```

This will scroll the table to a particular section at the top of the row.

if animated true it will give nice scrolling effect